# Does the $\chi^2$ test of variance rely on homoskedasticity?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, chi-squared-test, heteroscedasticity

I have a linear model $y=ax+b$. I have fit the relations using two data sets. I have found that estimate of $a$ from the two data sets are similar, but that the uncertainty of $a$ is much larger in one of the data sets. I am using the $\chi^2$ test of variance to show this. The test statistic is 
$$T=(N-1)(s/\sigma_0)^2$$
where $N$ is the number of points, $s$ is the standard deviation of $a$ from one of the data sets, and $\sigma^2$ is the standard deviation of $a$ from the other data set. I calculate $T$ and compare it to the $\chi^2$ distribution and find a p-value of $1e\mathrm{-}5$.

However, I know that $y=ax+b$ is heteroskedastic. Does this impact the test?

Comment: Almost certainly. Are these datasets from the same units (eg, patients), or are they unmatched? The $\sigma_0$ in your formula is supposed to be an s-priori value, not one estimated w/ error. This isn't likely the best way to test this. Can you say more about your study, your data, & your goals?

Comment: @gung I think the answer is that it tests for homoskedasticity rather than rely.  To say it relies on it means that homoskedasticity is assumed.  That woulld be nonsensical.

Comment: @gung yes the data are paired. Basically I am trying to demonstrate the importance of an effect that is usually neglected. So I have data set 1 which is raw data of $N$ objects, and data set 2 which is that exact same data 1 except with the effect accounted for. But the effect is small so it doesn't change the value of $a$, it only increases its uncertainty. It is important to estimate the uncertainty of $a$ correctly because its uncertainty propagates to other important things. So I want to show that the uncertainty of $a$ has been underestimated due to the neglect of this effect.

Comment: @gung is there a better test for what I am trying to demonstrate?

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I see your point. What I had in mind was that we are looking at 2 sets of residuals, & the idea is that the residuals are homoscedastic w/i each model, but their variance may differ between the models & we are trying to test the latter. I'm not sure what to do if each model is heteroscedastic & we want to test the variance of the 2 models for equality. Eg, imagine the variance is fan-shaped & 1 dataset sampled higher x-values than the other; how would we ever tell what's what? But maybe I'm just off-base, that's happened before.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron, hmmm. This seems like a different situation that I thought you were describing. Can you say more about your situation, the data, the models, & your goals? What are the variables, eg? Are they correlated? Can you paste in the model output that shows what you are referring to? If you added another variable, the residuals shouldn't be able to shrink, but there could be some collinearity or some other issue.

Comment: $T$ does not appear to be related to a chi-squared distribution: it is a multiple of a variable that has an $F$ ratio distribution when the two SD estimates are independent (and otherwise all bets are off).

Comment: @whuber What test would be appropriate in this situation?

Comment: @whuber I got the information about this test from here http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda358.htm

Comment: You appear to have misapplied that test.  It compares a sample variance to a *known* variance.  It does not compare two sample variances.

Comment: @whuber thanks, so I guess I should use the F-test for equality of two variances then? http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda359.htm Does this test rely on any assumption of homoskedasticity?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "homoscedasticity," because it could have several distinct meanings in this context.  After all, the F test is testing for one kind of heteroscedasticity!